# SignalR 504 error /signalr/connect longPolling

Tags: .net, amazon-ec2, signalr

I have SignalR working in our development environment and our qa environment but our production environment is giving me 504 errors for the:

GET /signalr/connect?transport=longPolling&connectionId=bf95d6d2-f6be-4736-965e-e5371c313a85&connectionData=%5B%5D HTTP/1.1
and
POST /signalr/send?transport=longPolling&connectionId=bf95d6d2-f6be-4736-965e-e5371c313a85 HTTP/1.1
calls.

Does anyone have any suggestions of what may be causing this problem?

Edit:
I see the signalr/connect request in the IIS logs but not the signalr/send request.

2012-03-15 14:51:51 W3SVC10020001 IP-0A502EFC 10.80.46.252 GET /signalr/connect transport=longPolling&connectionId=960cebb2-a99b-42bc-aea1-5819ef81a3a3&connectionData=%5B%5D 80 - 12.152.10.63 HTTP/1.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+rv:11.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/11.0 http://www.degreetree.com/trackingpixel/5/26/False www.degreetree.com 200 0 0 397 110572

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there negotiate request?
It should go first as far as I know. You get your connection id from it. Could you provide more information on 504. Does it contain any exception information?

Comment: The negotiate request was good. The SignalR was working correctly and the clients were getting fully connected, IE not firewal or proxy issues. Instead it was an issue outside of SignalR. Sometimes you should believe the results and dig deeper than the new thing that you are using...

Comment: Hey David...can you point me to the what was the exact issue here? :) Thanks